# encapsulate messageBox class inside another class

Tags: c#, class, object, encapsulation, messagebox

I want to encapsulate MessageBox Class inside another Class and pass this object to some method and get `Text`, `Caption`, `Buttons`, `Icon` for `MessageBox` from the method based on business logic, and show the message in calling method..

How can I do this?

Please show some code samples..

Comment: why down-Voting? Please mention the reason..

Comment: Have you tried it already? Please provide your sample code with the pain points.

Comment: @Fischermaen: I tried that, but there was some problem, which I got it solved now.. I have posted my answer

Comment: @dotNETbeginner you can create an Custom User Control with Visual Studio and use that as you're MessageBox ,because i think MessageBox.Show(); is a Static method and it creates a temporary built in user control to do that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MessageBoxObject
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public MessageBoxButtons Buttons { get; set; }

        public void Show()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Text,Caption,Buttons);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an instance of `MessageBox`.

You could, however, create a class which would hold all of the parameters needed to show a MessageBox, like so:

```
internal class MessageBoxParameters
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public MessageBoxButtons Buttons { get; set; }
    public MessageBoxIcon Icon { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
public static class MessageBoxUtilities
{
    public static DialogResult Show(MessageBoxParameters p)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(p.Text, p.Caption, p.Buttons, p.Icon);
    }
}
```